Оповещение через telegram бота
Хочу сделать оповещение через telegram бота(чтобы бот отправлял каждому зарегистрированному в нём пользователю сообщение) написал код , но он не работает (ошибки нет).
@bot.message_handler(commands=["notif_sup"])
def notif_sup(message):
    chat_id = 0
    all = []
    f = open("User_id.txt", "a+")
    f.seek(0, 0)
    tex = f.readlines()
    all.append(tex)
    f.close()

    while chat_id > 0:
        b = 0
        a = all[b]
        chat_id = int(a)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, "текст")

        b += 1


Для чего вы так усложняете простую задача, можно же сделать это все гораздо проще, например так:
@bot.message_handler(commands=["notif_sup"])
def notif_sup(message):
    with open('User_id.txt','r') as f:
        for chat_id in f:
            bot.send_message(chat_id, "текст")


Ваш цикл не начинается, смотрите:
chat_id = 0

Здесь вы присваиваете chat_id значение 0, до начала цикла не изменяете его.
А т.к. условие цикла
chat_id > 0

ложно, он не начнётся.
